# Help with heated differential pair design

Tags: circuit-design, bjt, datasheet, current-source

So I'm currently designing a VCO and need an exponential voltage-controlled current source. I'm following the basic idea of biasing one side of an NPN differential pair. However, I've seen that for better temperature stability, it is (or at least used to be) very common to use a common substrate transistor array such as a [CA3046](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/66311/INTERSIL/CA3046.html) and use two of them as a heater and a sensor. Reading about this, it seems the simplest way to do this is as shown in the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fno6BW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here \$Q_1\$ acts as a temperature sensor, and \$Q_2\$ as a heater, while \$V_\text{ref}\$ is a control voltage for the temperature. My design runs off a dual \$10\,\text{V}\$ supply, and looking at the datasheet, a safe option for the heater elements is just \$R_B=10\,\text k\Omega\$ and \$R_E=100\,\Omega\$, giving me a total power dissipation on \$Q_2\$ of approximately \$250\,\text{mW}\$ which is within the max ratings. I've seen circuits dissipating up to \$700\,\text{mW}\$ on this transistor, but I'm not sure if it's safe and I might be misinterpreting the datasheet.

Anyway, that's not my main issue. It now boils down to choosing \$R_S\$ and \$V_\text{ref}\$. Doing a simple Ebers-Moll model for \$Q_1\$ gives that the voltage \$V_S\$ on the positive op-amp input is

$$
V_S=V_++R_SI_{S}-V_TW_0\left(\frac{R_SI_S}{V_T}e^\frac{R_SI_S+V_+}{V_T}\right)
$$

with \$V_T\$ the thermal voltage, \$I_S\$ the emitter-base reverse saturation current, and \$W_0\$ the principal branch of the Lambert \$W\$ function. Using that \$V_+\gg V_T\$ this is pretty well approximated by just

$$V_S=V_T\log\frac{V_+}{R_SI_S},$$

so in priciple I need to choose \$R_S\$ and \$V_\text{ref}=V_S\$ to get the desired \$V_T\$, but for that I need to know \$I_S\$ at the desired working temperature. I wanted \$80\,^\circ\text C\$ but that's impossible given the \$300\,\text{mW}\$ power limit and \$180\,^\circ\text{C/W}\$ thermal resistance, so the working temperature is also up in the air at this point. My question is then, given the parameters present in the datasheet, how to estimate \$I_S\$ as a function of temperature?

Comment: Ibase = Is/Bn[exp(Ube/Ut)-1). You know Ut (Thermo-Voltage) and can characterize Ube/Ibase via a component Tester. Bn (Current-Amplification) can also be characterized via component Tester. You can use this to form Is(T)

Comment: Also my recommendation: Use a NTC<->Diode Series-circuit for temperatur sensing and then feed it into the heater. Is simpler. Except you want to build a high precision device. Feed the OP-Amp output directly into the sense resistor (without second BJT). You can use a "high-current" audio amplifier as-well. You dont need high slew-rates bandwith or stuff like that. You need drift-stability (E.g. chopper-amp) and low offset( You could use compensation for this).

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent So you're suggesting measuring \$I_S\$ myself? That works, but I'd rather estimate it from typical values in the datasheet, or maybe find a model that would give me a more direct relationship between \$V_T\$ and \$V_\text{ref}\$. About your other suggestion, that doesn't work. Both BJTs in the schematic are part of the same die and are intended for precise setting of the substrate temperature itself, as exponential current sources are highly temperature sensitive. I can't measure the temperature externally.

Comment: And as a matter of fact, the actual temperature reading is not important, all I care about is \$V_T\$, because that's the parameter that shows up in the differential pair exponential converter, \$I=I_0\exp(V/V_T)\$. I want to heat up the die to a particular choice of \$V_T\$.

Comment: Hmmmh Is is mainly/exclusively determined by your junction design and your doping process parameters. I guess you wont find any of these in common Datasheets. You can of course characterize a given series of devices accross batches or ask the manufacturer - but i guess you will have to spend a pretty $ in quantity over a few years / or be a brand like Fluke or what-not to get this information.

Comment: But you could get lucky: You need B(Uce) and Ube(T) with IBase(T) to form the required equations (numercially) - if you get these out of datasheets you can work with them.